# jstree contextmenu with a foreign node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Currently I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to attach the default contextmenu jstree uses, to a foreign node ?

To explain my scenario please go to [this link](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd) and go to the bottom of the page. In the first demo you can drag'n'drop a foreign node (being "I have the jstree-draggable class") to the folders in jstree. 
I'm trying to understand if it's possible to attach the jstree contextmenu plugin to that foreign node?

Comment: It's certainly possible, though you'll have to either modify `show_contextmenu` in jstree source to have it accept non-nodes, or override it with your own method, maybe pilfering from the source as necessary. Since foreign contextual items should have less tree-relevant actions, it might be a good idea just to steal the code/style and create a separate context menu for foreign nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible to attach contextmenu to foreign nodes in jstree. 
You should keep in mind, though, you'll need to rewrite a lot of code if you're using different html from what you have in the tree.

In my case this was not acceptable because I had to rewrite more than half of the library so I could get it to work with my html structure.

Creating a separate context menu (as @Jed suggested) is also an option - if you have the time to deal with all the problems that will come. :)